# Determine number of rows per minute using Entity ObjectContext and with For loop iteration

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a SQL Server 2008 table with a column of `datetime` data type. I'd like a entity query that produces the number of rows for each minute interval. For example, the results would look like this:

```
1. 7/3/2011 14:00:00 | 1000
2. 7/3/2011 14:01:00 | 1097
```

The first row would mean that 1000 rows have a `datetime` value between 7/3/2011 13:59:00 and 7/3/2011 14:00:00.

The second row would mean that 1097 rows have a `datetime` value between 7/3/2011 14:00:00 and 7/3/2011 14:01:00.

I can get this result with this sql query

```
select 
stamp = dateadd(mi,datediff(mi,0,[date]) + 1,0),
rows = count(1) from WMLSLog group by dateadd(minute,datediff(mi,0,[date])+1,0) 
order by stamp asc
```

Result:

```
- stamp                 rows
- 2012-03-03 16:54:00.000   55
- 2012-03-03 16:55:00.000   120
- 2012-03-03 16:56:00.000   120
```

Can someone help me to get this using Entity Framework

```
public IQueryable<WMLSLog> GetWMLSLogs()
    {
        var result = this.ObjectContext.WMLSLogs..........;
        //This returns a DateStamp and Count
    }
```

Or a for loop to get the result from the `IQueryable<WMLSLog>` returned collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After good amount of research I found that .Net 4 got most of the sql functions under System.Data.Objects.SqlClient. It has most of the common sql functions like DateDiff, DateAdd etc.
So I used them in side my Entity to Linq query.

```
 DateTime zeroDate = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        this.ObjectContext.WMLSLogs.GroupBy(s => SqlFunctions.DateAdd("mi", ((SqlFunctions.DateDiff("mi", zeroDate, s.Date))), zeroDate)).
            Select(g => new
                {
                    Date = g.Key,
                    count = g.Count()
                }).OrderBy(x => x.Date);
```

And I got the expected result.